# onclick event its opening both calendars

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using two uib datepickers

The `onclick` event is opening both calendars.

How do I fix this ?

My code:

HTMl

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>From date - </p>
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" show-button-bar="false"
        ng-model="fd" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2019-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"
        name="from_date" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>To date - </p>
    <p class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" show-button-bar="false"
        ng-model="td" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"
        name="to_date" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="opendate($event)">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
$scope.today = function () {
  $scope.fd = new Date();
  $scope.td = new Date();
};
$scope.today();

$scope.clear = function () {
  $scope.fd = null;
  $scope.td = null;
};

// Disable weekend selection
/*$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
};*/

$scope.toggleMin = function () {
  $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
};
$scope.toggleMin();

$scope.open = function ($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();

  $scope.opened = true;
};

$scope.opendate = function ($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();

  $scope.opened = true;
};

$scope.dateOptions = {
  formatYear: 'yy',
  startingDay: 1
};

$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
```

Comment: You used **$scope.opened** in both date pickers. Change to any other name will work

Answer (score 2):

You have used only one variable `$scope.opened` for both the datepicker.

You have to use two separate scope variables like

```
$scope.openDatePicker1 //and  
$scope.openDatePicker2
```

and need to assign these variables to

```
is-open="openDatePicker1" //and 
is-open="openDatePicker2"
```

respectively for each datepicker.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have used same open variable for both the uib-datepicker

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', 
['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.today = function() { 
    $scope.fd = new Date();
    $scope.td = new Date();
};
$scope.today();

$scope.clear = function () {
    $scope.fd = null;
    $scope.td = null;
};

// Disable weekend selection
/*$scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
    return ( mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ) );
};*/

$scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
};
$scope.toggleMin();

$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened1 = true;
};

$scope.opendate = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened2 = true;
};

$scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
};

$scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/qJHxf5q4q6b0QPLSn7pQ?p=preview)